# Google Maps API + populate textfields with bounds data on click event

Tags: php, html, google-maps-api-3

What is a good way to approach this, I have the map functioning and when you click on the map it populates some global variables.  Once clicking the google map I would like the lat/lng values returned from the click event to to fill values in a couple text boxes.

I figure php could be used to populate the  value

```
<label for="textfield3">Square Number :</label>
<input type="text" value="<?PHP echo $squareNum; ?>" />
```

but I am thinking that this needs to be written such that the click event reloads the textfield??

Comment: PHP really isn't good for this solution. You want to have Javascript running on the page that intercepts the click event on the google map, then uses the event data that is passed through there to populate the input fields.

Comment: What does your existing code look like?  If you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates what you have, it would be simpler to help you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to capture and update that text field, you'll want to use Javascript bound to the map object that you create using the Google Maps Javascript API.

**HTML**

```
<div id="map"></div>
...
<input type="text" id="lat" />
<input type="text" id="lng" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function initMap() {
  // Map config
  var myLatlng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  // lat and lng text box references
  var latText = document.getElementById('lat');
  var lngText = document.getElementById('lng');

  // this is the global map object
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  });

  map.addListener('click', function(e){
      latText.value = e.latLng.lat();
      lngText.value = e.latLng.lng();
  });
}
```

Note that if you have markers on the map, or any other element (Polygons, Polylines, etc.), the click events for those elements will *not* trigger the map's click event, and you'll have to have separate `addListener` bindings for each of those elements.

Comment: So just to clarify, I currently have a map that loads on the page, when you click one of the drawn polygons it populates a variable square number (which is the square value associated with the polygon and currently pops up in infowindow).  On that click event I want to fill the  textfield with the results of the click event (which I will later replicate for the other boxes).  As I understand this, I already have the javascript that captures the click event and populates a variable...what I need to do is link that value to the text field (basically so users dont have to copy and paste the event

Comment: @chris Yes, and you can set that with `[theNameOfYourTextFieldVariable].value = "new value";`

Comment: in HTML <label for="textfield3">Square Number :</label>
    
    <input type="text" value="<?PHP echo $textfield3_new; ?>" /> and within the add listener in Javascript [textfield3_new].value = "new value"; (just useing "new value" until I see that something populates that text box)????

Comment: @chris You have to set an id for the `input`, like `<input id='testing' />` and then get that element using `var myTextBox = document.getElementById('testing');`